# Could anyone inform me what tree this is?

Tags: identification, trees

Its a kind of tree that if cut they will reroot & grow.  I originally started with 3.  [image: Tree in question:]

[image: Cropped image]

Comment: I need a picture of the leaves in a branch

Comment: What part of the world is this in, can you add a close up of the leaf as I can't make out the shape.

Comment: We need a close-up of the leaf, and ideally of any flowers or fruit.

Comment: They look like acer Tempreste